# Most straightforward way to create a pill looking item in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

Trying to find a way to create an item that looks like the disabled mat-chip but with a specific color("accent") and no check mark

[image]

I've tried a few different approaches but no luck

```html
  <mat-chip-set>
    <mat-chip color="primary" *ngIf="inConfig">
      edit mode</mat-chip>
    <mat-chip-option disabled selected color="accent" *ngIf="inConfig">
      edit mode</mat-chip-option>
    <mat-chip-option defaultColor="accent" selected color="primary" *ngIf="inConfig">
      edit mode</mat-chip-option>
    <button mat-raised-button *ngIf="inConfig" selected color='warn'>edit mode</button>
    <mat-card>
      <mat-card-content *ngIf="inConfig" color="accent">edit mode</mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
    
  </mat-chip-set>
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason to even require Angular here. Just some basic HTML and CSS should meet what you need, turn it into a component and call it a day?

```css
.pill {
background-color:gray;
border-radius: 25px;
width: 50px;
}

.pill-text {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pill">
<div class="pill-text">Pill</div>
</div>
```

Or, a quick and dirty example as a component:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ty1u55?file=src/pill/pill.component.ts

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In response to @AustinTFrench I wanted it to be angular for consistency with the rest of the code. The solution was to make a button and to use a mixin to pass in the color information

```html
button id= "edit-mode-pill" mat-raised-button disabled>edit mode</button>
```

```html
@mixin color($theme){
  // Get the color config from the theme.
  $color-config: mat.get-color-config($theme);
  // Get the accent color palette from the color-config.
  $accent-palette: map.get($color-config, 'accent');
  #edit-mode-pill{
    background-color: mat.get-color-from-palette($accent-palette, 500);
    color: white;
    border-radius: 16px; 
  }
}
```

[image]